# VS Code debugger no longer accepting input

Tags: visual-studio-code

Strangely, VS Code stopped accepting input from integrated and external terminals. It was working with fish as the shell on Arch an hour ago. If I run the following Python code, for example:

```py
print('Please enter a number: ', end='')
a = float(input())
print(f'Your number is: {a}')
```

and I type `1` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the cursor moves to the next line and all execution halts. The debugger is still running as if I didn't enter anything, but the terminal is displaying my input. When I hit *stop*, I see the error "timeout after 1000ms" as an alert in the lower right of VS Code.

I haven't made any changes to *launch.json* after generating from the *Python: Current File* option. For clarity's sake, that code is here:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

I haven't found any resolution by reading the docs. Is this just a bug that will get fixed, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

Executing the code from the shell normally runs as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13449
check this out, try downgrade the extension back to another version.

Comment: Downgrading worked; I'll keep my eye out for a fix. Also, I was looking in the wrong repository for this bug, so I'm very glad you found the right one. Thanks for your help!